# Angular translate - partialLoader dynamically change urlTemplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, angular-translate

I am using angular translate in my webapp. In specific, I use **Asynchronous loaders** with **partialLoader.**

An example of my config is:

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
  urlTemplate: '/i18n/{part}/{lang}.json'
});
```

As you can see, I specify the urlTemplate of all the json file. What if I want to pack all the *.js file for production and minify purpose?
When I minify all the `*.js` files, I have all my application deployed in `app/*` path. So the `.json` file are not anymore in the urlTemplate path specified in the $translateProvider.

How can I set **dynamically** the urlTemplate for the json translation files?

Comment: I would probably change my build process to have the translations files separate from the main minified file for your app. At the moment, if I understand correctly, all your translations would be in your application, delivered to the user up-front and in full, so that would perhaps lose the advantage of partial loading and asynchronous loading?